# Bootstrap CSS: how to override padding to default unspecified?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap Pagination, all the examples here are using it aligned to left of parent; while in cases I want to make it center aligned, horizontally; I have tried the inline style `margin: 0 auto` and `display: inline-block; or block` and many other ways, but it's still not working, in Chrome Dev Tools I can see it's because it has a `.pagination` class which defined `padding-left: 0;` that stopped from being center aligned, from the DevTool I can uncheck the line of `padding-left: 0;` and it becomes center aligned;

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css

```
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

So, for overriding, I know it's easy to override it to be another value, but if I override to another specific number, it would not be responsive to window dimension changes, I've tried to set `padding: auto;` but auto seems not valid for padding? I wonder is there anyway to override it to be unspecified? like uncheck it from DevTool?

Comment: Is `padding: initial;` what you're looking for? Or `padding-left: initial;` if it's just the left you want.

Comment: Add a working example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Should be able to just put `text-align: center;` on the parent

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `text-align: center;` on the parent container of the nav container. In [this page here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) it works fine if doing it with dev tools. Find the class `.bs-example` and add `text -align: center` too see it work there.

Oddly enough the `padding-left: 0;` actually keeps it centered because of the ghost button/space to the left of the left navigation arrow.